# IOS - Collision Detection on Sprites using Cocos2d

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

In this game I have asteroids flying down from to top of screen, and a ship you can move freely, but I have added some collision detection and it does not seem to work in the update method when I call `[self scheduleupdate];`

```
// Import the interfaces
#import "HelloWorldLayer.h"

// Needed to obtain the Navigation Controller
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#pragma mark - HelloWorldLayer

// HelloWorldLayer implementation
@implementation HelloWorldLayer

// Helper class method that creates a Scene with the HelloWorldLayer as the only child.
+(CCScene *) scene
{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object.
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object.
    HelloWorldLayer *layer = [HelloWorldLayer node];

    // add layer as a child to scene
    [scene addChild: layer];

    // return the scene
    return scene;
}

// on "init" you need to initialize your instance
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init]) ) {
        self.isTouchEnabled = YES;

        moveLeft = NO;
        moveRight = NO;

        speed = 3;
        fireSpeed = 8;

        fireArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
        CCSprite *bg = [[CCSprite alloc] initWithFile:@"space_bg.jpg"];
        [bg setPosition:ccp(160, 240)];
        CGSize imageSize = bg.contentSize;
        bg.scaleX = winSize.width / imageSize.width;
        bg.scaleY = winSize.height / imageSize.height;
        bg.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
        [self addChild:bg];

        ship = [[CCSprite alloc] initWithFile:@"ship.png"];
        [ship setPosition:ccp(100, 100)];
        [self addChild:ship];
        [self schedule:@selector(fireLoop:)];

        NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                                          target:self
                                                        selector:@selector(fireCreate)
                                                        userInfo:nil
                                                         repeats:YES];

        asteroidArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
            CCSprite *asteroid = [[CCSprite alloc] initWithFile:@"asteroid1.png"];
            [asteroidArray addObject:asteroid];
        }

        [self asteroidCreate];
        [self scheduleUpdate];
    }
    return self;
}

CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet;
NSMutableArray *asteroidAnimFrames;

- (float)randomValueBetween:(float)low andValue:(float)high {
    return (((float) arc4random() / 0xFFFFFFFFu) * (high - low)) + low;
}


-(void)updtate:(ccTime)dt{
    CGPoint shipPosition = [ship position];
    for(int i = 0; i < asteroidArray.count; i++){

        CCSprite *asteroid = [asteroidArray objectAtIndex:i];
        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ship.boundingBox, asteroid.boundingBox)) {
            NSLog(@"hit");
        }
    }
}

- (void)countDownToCreateNextAsteroid {
    int minTime = 1;
    int maxTime = 10;

    int randomTime = (arc4random() % (3));

    id countdownDelay = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:randomTime];
    id creationMethod = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(asteroidCreate)];

    id countdownToCreateSeq = [CCSequence actions:countdownDelay, creationMethod, nil];

    [self stopAllActions];
    [self runAction:countdownToCreateSeq];
}

-(void)asteroidCreate {

    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"asteroids.plist"];
    spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"asteroids.png"];

    asteroidAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];

    for(int i=1; i <= 8; i++) {
        [asteroidAnimFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"asteroid%d.png", i]]];
    }
    CCAnimation *moveAsteroidAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:asteroidAnimFrames delay:0.1f];

    CCSprite *asteroid = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"asteroid1.png"];
    int x = arc4random() % 320;
    int y = arc4random() % 480;
    asteroid.position = ccp(x, 480);
    CCAction *asteroidAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:moveAsteroidAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO]];

    [asteroidArray addObject:asteroid];

    int q = arc4random() % 320;
    int r = arc4random() % 10;
    CCAction *moveAction = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:r position:ccp(q, -50)];

    id asteroidRemove = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^
                         {
                             [asteroid removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
                             [asteroidArray removeObject:asteroid];
                         }];

    id asteroidSeq = [CCSequence actions:moveAction, asteroidRemove, nil];
    [asteroid runAction:asteroidSeq];
    [asteroid runAction:asteroidAction];
    [spriteSheet addChild:asteroid];
    [self addChild:spriteSheet];

    [self countDownToCreateNextAsteroid];
}

-(void)fireLoop:(ccTime)fl {

    if(fireArray.count > 0){

        for(int i = 0; i < fireArray.count; i++){
            CCSprite *tmpFire = [fireArray objectAtIndex:i];
            if(tmpFire.position.y < 500){
                [tmpFire setPosition:ccp([tmpFire position].x, [tmpFire position].y + fireSpeed)];
            }else{
                [fireArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];
            }
        }
    } else {

    }
}

-(void)fireCreate{

    int shootPositionX = [ship position].x;
    int shootPositionY = ([ship position].y) + 35;

    CCSprite *fire;
    fire = [[CCSprite alloc] initWithFile:@"fire.png"];
    [fire setPosition:ccp(shootPositionX, shootPositionY)];
    [fireArray addObject:fire];
    [self addChild:fire];

    [fire release];
}

-(void)gameLoop:(ccTime)dt {

    int shipPositionX = 41/2;

    if([ship position].x > shipPositionX){
        [ship setPosition:ccp([ship position].x - speed, [ship position].y)];
    }
}

-(void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event  {
    for(UITouch *t in touches){
        CGPoint point = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:t];
        //if(point.x <= 160){
        //    moveRight = NO;
        //    moveLeft = YES;
        //}else{
        //    moveRight =YES;
        //    moveLeft = NO;
        //}

        if(allowedToMove)
            [ship setPosition:ccp(point.x, point.y + 76)];
    }
}

-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    for(UITouch *t in touches){
        CGPoint point = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:t];

        int shipX = [ship position].x;
        int shipY = [ship position].y;

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(CGRectMake (shipX - 20.5, shipY - 96, 50, 50), point))
        {
            allowedToMove = true;
        }
    }
}




-(void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    for(UITouch *t in touches){
        CGPoint point = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:t];
        allowedToMove = false;
    }
}

// on "dealloc" you need to release all your retained objects
- (void) dealloc
{
    // in case you have something to dealloc, do it in this method
    // in this particular example nothing needs to be released.
    // cocos2d will automatically release all the children (Label)

    // don't forget to call "super dealloc"
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark GameKit delegate

-(void) achievementViewControllerDidFinish:(GKAchievementViewController *)viewController
{
    AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [[app navController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

-(void) leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish:(GKLeaderboardViewController *)viewController
{
    AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [[app navController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
@end
```

Comment: 1) "does not seem to work" is not a problem description (always provide a detailed problem description, including any error messages, call stack, etc) 2) just pasting your entire code isn't inviting users to help 3) use basic debugging techniques (breakpoints, NSLog, ...) to check whether code runs or not 4) it's Coco**s**2d, not Coco**a**2d 5) your update method is misspelled: 'upd**t**ate'

Comment: As said by,LearnCocos2D, misspelled 'updtate' . so even after schedule update, your update function won't be called.

Comment: HI, thanks for you replies, yes the slog is printing out the word "hit" now thank you